# JsHint in Visual Studio 2013 Web Essentials Ignores the .jshintrc File

Tags: jshint, web-essentials

> ... but the answer doesn't work.

- I have a .jshintrc file in C:\Users\UserName\
- I have copied default settings from https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc
- I have set `"unused" : false`
- I have closed and reopened Visual Studio 2013
- I have rebuilt the project.

Why does JsHint continue to show "unused" errors? Further troubleshooting...

- I have deleted any additional .jshintrc files on the computer.
- I have put a .jshintrc file in the root solution folder.
- I have put a .jshintrc file in the root project folder.
- I have then restarted Visual Studio 2013.

Still it shows the "unused" error. What gives? Further troubleshooting

- I have updated Web Essentials from 1.8.5 to 1.9.

Still no dice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use JsHint ".jshintrc" file with Visual Studio 2013 Web Essentials extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20529664/how-do-you-use-jshint-jshintrc-file-with-visual-studio-2013-web-essentials-ex)

Comment: Yup. It's a duplicate. That said, the other question's answer didn't help.